# Преобразовать строку

Tags: php

```
echo $file_contents;
```

На выходе так:

строка 1 - пустая строка

строка 2 - key 1, key 2, key 3, key 4, key 5

Example

```
1 - тут пустая строка
key 1, key 2, key 3, key 4, key 5
```

Как преобразовать строку в такой вид:

```
<li>key 1</li>
<li>key 2</li>
<li>key 3</li>
<li>key 4</li>
<li>key 5</li>
```

Также нужно убрать первую, пустую строку. ((

**Обновление**

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://test.com/?key='.$keys2); //Просто пример

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

$file_contents = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$file_contents = strip_tags($file_contents);

$file_contents = str_replace('["'.$keys2.'",[','',$file_contents);

$file_contents = str_replace(']]','',$file_contents);

$file_contents = str_replace('"','',$file_contents);

$file_contents = str_replace('['.$keys2.',','',$file_contents);

$file_contents = str_replace('[','',$file_contents);

echo $file_contents;
```

Comment: @allanklinton, вы данные берёте из файла?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мало информации дали, но пробуйте так:

```
$arr = explode(', ',trim($file_contents));
$list = '';
foreach($arr as $val){
    $list .= '<li>'. $val .'</li>';
}
echo $list;
```

P.S. На всякий случай, хотя и может быть излишним, можно разбивать четко по запятой, а после удалить лишние пробелы в элементах массива:

```
$arr = explode(',',trim($file_contents));
$arr = array_map('trim',$arr);
// дальше всё так же
```

Comment: @Deonis, по перовому вышло так:

<li>chris kyle and keyser soze,john key,milton keynes,keyboard symbols glossary,key west all inclusive resorts,free product key codes,list of all keyboard symbols,typing keyboard lessons,window 7 product key free,florida keys vacation packages</li>

Не совсем правильно... можете подправить?

Comment: @allanklinton, я ж говорю, что мало информации дали. У вас в переменной **$file_contents** множество строк? И каждую из них нужно обработать отдельно, "перепаковав" в списки?

Comment: @Deonis, на выходе  $file_contents
["key",
["chris kyle and <span class=\"suggest\">key</span>ser soze","john <span class=\"suggest\">key</span>","milton <span class=\"suggest\">key</span>nes","<span class=\"suggest\">key</span>board symbols glossary","<span class=\"suggest\">key</span> west all inclusive resorts","free product <span class=\"suggest\">key</span> codes","list of all <span class=\"suggest\">key</span>board symbols","typing <span class=\"suggest\">key</span>board lessons","window 7 product <span class=\"suggest\">key</span> free"]]

Comment: Да, каждую отдельно надо преобразовать

Comment: @allanklinton, вы меня совсем запутали. Это похоже на массив, но ... как-то же вы обрабатывали это дело строковыми функциями: str_replace и strip_tags... В общем, если это всё-таки строка, то второй вариант в ответе - ваш:

    $arr = explode(',',trim($file_contents));
    $arr = array_map('trim',$arr);
    $list = '';
    foreach($arr as $val){
        $list .= '<li>'. $val .'</li>';
    }
    echo $list;

Comment: Спасибо, я как раз его смотрел!

Comment: @allanklinton, не за что, но мне не дает покоя вид массива )) Вот [смотрите по ссылке][1]. Это то, что вы мне дали в комментарии. Заметили, как красивенько всё массивом выводится? ;)

   [1]:http://ideone.com/E3xh3Y

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать более гибкий подход применяя regex-ы: есть возможность отследить пробельные символы (пробелы, перенос строк,...) до и после запятой.

```
$content = 'chris kyle and keyser soze,john key, milton keynes ,keyboard symbols glossary,
key west all inclusive resorts,free product key codes,list of all keyboard symbols,typing keyboard lessons,
window 7 product key free,florida keys vacation packages';

$result = preg_replace('/\s*([^,]+)\b\s*,?/', "<li>$1</li>\n", trim($content));

print_r($result);
```

[Смотрите результат](http://ideone.com/S8b94P).

За универсальность и короткую запись частенько приходится платить производительностью, т.е. применение строковых функций является приоритетным. Правда, в данном конкретном примере разница едва заметна.

[Мой вариант с `preg_replace`](http://3v4l.org/lnpVB/perf#tabs).

[Вариант, предложенный [[@Deonis](/users/4058/deonis)](/users/4058/deonis)](http://3v4l.org/Yn9R4/perf#tabs).